# table layout inside relative layout

Tags: android

is it possible to use table layout in relative layout. for example:

in main.xml:

```
< RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"  
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TableRow 
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" > 

<TextView  
            android:id="@+id/textView9"  
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:textSize="18dp"  
            android:text="Weather Table"  
            android:gravity="center"> < /TextView>

</ TableRow>
</ TableLayout>
</ RelativeLayout>
```

how can i use two type of layout in single xml file.

Comment: What is the problem with the above code? You can use nested layouts in Android.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1-Delete namespace that you assigned to TableLayout("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android").It would be seems as:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Weather Table"
                android:textSize="18dp" >
            </TextView>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

2-Your tags has incorrect blank spaces,for example `</ TableRow>`.Use `</TableRow>` instead of it.

Comment: but it will shown force close at the run time,, whats the problem in above code

Comment: @user1500635 You'r xml file has incorrect indent.I edit it,so you can use it.

Comment: thanks but i want to use table layout inside of relative layout,,so i want to use both layout in single xml file,,and in my xml all the tags are correctly declared in xml but still shows force close error,,in log cat it shows the error such as unable to open activity component info table layout

Comment: @user1500635 I'm sorry.I wrote complete code but it was not shown.Please see it again.

Answer (score 1):

```
I am never using this but this is helps you.
```

make drawable/table_shape.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape= "rectangle"  >
        <solid android:color="#000"/>
        <stroke android:width="1dp"  android:color="#ff9"/>
</shape>
```

layout/my_table.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TableRow android:id="@+id/tabla_cabecera" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"></TableRow>
            <TableLayout android:id="@+id/tabla_cuerpo" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent">
                <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView android:background="@drawable/cell_shape" android:padding="5dp" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:text="TextView"></TextView>
                    <TextView android:background="@drawable/cell_shape" android:padding="5dp" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:text="TextView"></TextView>
                    <TextView android:background="@drawable/cell_shape" android:padding="5dp" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:text="TextView"></TextView>

                </TableRow>
                <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow2" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">                    

                    <TextView android:background="@drawable/cell_shape" android:padding="5dp" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:text="TextView"></TextView>
                    <TextView android:background="@drawable/cell_shape" android:padding="5dp" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:text="TextView"></TextView>
                    <TextView android:background="@drawable/cell_shape" android:padding="5dp" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:text="TextView"></TextView></TableRow>

                <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow3" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">                    

                    <TextView  android:background="@drawable/cell_shape" android:padding="5dp" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:text="TextView"></TextView>
                    <TextView android:background="@drawable/cell_shape" android:padding="5dp" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:text="TextView"></TextView>
                    <TextView android:background="@drawable/cell_shape" android:padding="5dp" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:text="TextView"></TextView>

                </TableRow>
                <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow4" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">                    

                    <TextView android:background="@drawable/cell_shape" android:padding="5dp" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:text="TextView"></TextView>
                    <TextView android:background="@drawable/cell_shape" android:padding="5dp" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:text="TextView"></TextView>
                    <TextView  android:background="@drawable/cell_shape" android:padding="5dp" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:text="TextView"></TextView>

                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have very recently done this, here is the code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/tl"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TableRow>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Bkanban"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/left_arrow" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ETnew_task"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="500"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:hint="@string/to_do"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Bplus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="+"></Button>
    </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```